# Selecting records from table with father and sons relationships

Tags: sql, sql-server, hierarchical-data, recursive-query

I am using a SQL-SERVER database. How can I select all the records related by "padre" field? Example:

[image: table with info]

For example, selecting all records related to record with `CODIGO='AA'`.

Comment: Sorry... It is a SQL-SERVER. Instead of "clave='AA'" it should have been said: "codigo='AA'";

Comment: Hi @Karim if any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You did not specify what database you are using and the table's name, so I'm going to punch something general:

```
select *
from table_name
where padre='AA';
```

---

At first you said "related to `padre` field that is conflicting to `clave='AA'` so the above was my answer. I'm adding a new answer with the below query. Below is a query that selects all the records where `codigo='AA'` :

```
select *
from table_name
where codigo='AA';
```

Comment: Thank you, but it is not that simple. I was asking if there is a direct way of selecting records related to some other record. Imagine you have in a table items and also their components. You want to select all the items that make up a given item. You can say your item is a "car", you have "motor", belonging to that car, but you have componentes belonging to "motor". You want to select ALL of them. In my table, all items with a information in "padre" column are related to item with codigo="AA".

Answer (score 0):

This worked fine:

SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM articulo ORDER BY padre, codigo) sorteado, (SELECT @pv := 'AA') INITIALISATION WHERE find_in_set(padre, @pv) AND length(@pv := concat(@pv, ',', codigo));